# How can I get this square to go side to side in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to get this square to go across my screen and back along the path it came by but it just stays where it is. It's a clash between two if statements and I have tried using a break statement but that just stopped everything.

```
if squareX < 100:
    squareX += 1
elif squareX > 900:
    squareX -= 1
```

Comment: Add variable `direction` with value of 1 – it moves forward. When your object touch the right bounds of screen set `direction` to -1. When it touches left bounds set to 1. It's important to change direction only once when object touches bounds. In your movement loop use `squareX += 1 * direction` to get set valid movement.

Comment: @Daniel This worked apart from when it got to the left bounds of the screen. Here's the code now: `squareX += 1*direction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *state* in your game, which describes in which directions your rect moves. So when you go out of screen, this *state* changes.

When you update your game (which is one of the three things you do in your main loop: handle events, update the game state, draw the game), you look at your state and decide in which direction you move your rect. Then you check if it's out of the screen.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import pygame

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 32, 32)
    direction = 1
    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        rect.move_ip(direction * 3, 0)
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(rect):
            direction *= -1

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), rect)
        clock.tick(120)
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

easy, you first need to understand what a sprite class is.
follow the following code:

```
import pygame
class MovingSquare(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, location, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        image_surface = pygame.surface.Surface([30, 30])
        image_surface.fill([0,0,0])
        self.image = image_surface.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
        self.speed=speed
    def move(self):
        self.rect=self.rect.move(self.speed)
        if self.rect.right>screen.get_width() or self.rect.left<0:
            self.speed[0]=-self.speed[0]
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
x=5
y=0
squareX=MovingSquare([50, 50], [x, y])
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
running=True
while running:
    clock.tick(30)
    square.move()
    screen.blit(squareX.image, squareX.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False
pygame.quit()
```

the only problem is that it doesn't erase it's tracks so i suggest using an image file instead.